Error `Request failed "304 Not Modified"` when running `yarn create` with Sanity CLI on Windows 11
I’m encountering the following issue when trying to run yarn create to set up a Sanity project:
PS C:\Users\malan\Desktop\Programming Shit\Mern Projects\yc_directory> yarn create sanity@latest --project wl1d7zqt --dataset production --template clean --typescript --output-path studio-yc_directory
yarn create v1.22.22
warning package.json: No license field
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
error Error: https://registry.npmjs.org/fs-constants/-/fs-constants-1.0.0.tgz: Request failed "304 Not Modified"
    at ResponseError.ExtendableBuiltin (C:\Users\malan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:696:66)
    at new ResponseError (C:\Users\malan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:802:124)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\malan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:66750:16)
    at Request.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at module.exports.Request.onRequestResponse (C:\Users\malan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:142287:10)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient (node:_http_client:710:27)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (node:_http_common:117:17)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (node:_http_client:552:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/create for documentation about this command.

My environment:

Operating System: Windows 11
nvm version: 1.1.12
Node.js version: v23.4.0
npm version: 11.0.0
Yarn version: 1.22.22

Things I’ve tried so far:

Clearing the Yarn cache (yarn cache clean)
Deleting and reinstalling Node.js entirely

Despite these efforts, I continue to face the same issue. Any suggestions on how to fix this or what else I could try?
Update:
I also tried switching to a different version of Node.js using nvm, but the issue persists.
Thanks in advance for your help!

https://status.npmjs.org/incidents/bxvmmvlqzfds

So was it a npm issue , i thought i corrupted my file system ;(((

@Pointy this kind of incident i have heard of for the first time . Can you please elaborate on it more ,please ?
